# Checking if item is already in database before adding it

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

I'm adding articles into a database. That worked fine, except, while the database doesn't let me create duplicates during a session, once I log out and log back in, it does. I didn't want duplicates, so I added these new lines:

```
maybe_existing_article = Article.query.filter_by(url=article.url)
if (maybe_existing_article):
    article = maybe_existing_article.url
    return "exists"
```

But that didn't work, I get "print("article.id=" + str(article.id))
NameError: name 'article' is not defined".

Here is the relevant code, including the new lines.

```
##############################################
@app.route('/bootstrap', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bootstrap():
    posted = 1
    print ("bootstrap")
    global article
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['title'] or not request.form['url'] or not request.form['image_url'] or not request.form['snippet']:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')
        else:
            article = Article(request.form['title'], request.form['url'], request.form['image_url'],
                               request.form['snippet'])
            maybe_existing_article = Article.query.filter_by(url=article.url)
            if (maybe_existing_article):
                article = maybe_existing_article.url
                return "exists"
            else:
                db.session.add(article)
                try:
                    db.session.commit()
                except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
                   flash('Article url already exists, failed to post new article')
                   posted = 0
                   #return render_template('/error.html', article_url=article.url)

                article_list = Article.query.filter_by(url=article.url)
                if posted == 1:
                    flash('Record was successfully added')
                else:
                    db.session.rollback()
                    article_list = Article.query.filter_by(url=article.url)
                    article=article_list[0]

                print ("article.id=" + str(article.id))
                import json
                print("a")
                return json.dumps(article.id)

    else:
        print("article.id=" + str(article.id))
        urlNumber = str(article.id)

        message = {'greeting':urlNumber}
        return jsonify(message)  # serialize and use JSON headers
```

And here's the create_tables.py:

```
article_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article (
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title       TEXT NOT NULL,
    url         TEXT NOT NULL,
    image_url   TEXT NOT NULL,
    snippet     TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_upload TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        CONSTRAINT article_unq UNIQUE (url)
);"""
```

Comment: This constraint should be baked into your database. Make the `url` field `unique` and then just insert. Make sure to handle failed inserts, e.g. due to violations of the unique constraint.

Comment: It's already supposed to be doing that ---         CONSTRAINT article_unq UNIQUE (url) is in my table. Hmmm so why would that only be working during a session?

Comment: If you have a unique constraint on that column the database should prevent duplicates within a session, between sessions, across simultaneous sessions; really, in all cases. Are you 100% sure that that constraint exists? If you look at your data, do you really see multiple records with the same URL?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately --- I have an HTML home page that constantly lists everything in the database, and it shows duplicates if I add them after logging out and in. That's how I noticed the problem.

Comment: Again, that shouldn't be possible. If you inspect your _database_ (not the web interface; maybe there's a bad query or something giving duplicate records) do you see duplicate records? And do you see the proper constraint?

Comment: Are the duplicate URLs _exactly_ the same? Same case? Same formatting, e.g. trailing `/`? Same query parameters?

Comment: Ah, you're right --- I didn't realize it, but the website I'm pulling the URLs from changes the URLs slightly when you log in and log out. I think I should be able to fix that by making image_url rather than url the unique (image_url remains stable across sessions). Just tried it, and it doesn't seem to work --- thinking I probably need to alter it through connecting to the SQL server, which I cannot figure out how to do, womp (can't find mysql on my system anywhere somehow, though i can find the .db just fine). But at least I know what's wrong.

Comment: "I think I should be able to fix that by making image_url rather than url the unique (image_url remains stable across sessions)"—or dedupe the URLs, if there's a clear way of doing that. Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Unique constraint at the table that you want and catch the error when you try to insert a row that was already inserted. In SQLite, you can't add this constraint after the Table is created, so you would need to create the table again.

You can also add an Unique Index to the table that works almost the same:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name(column_name);`

If you can't do that, you can always send a SELECT to that table with the ID you are trying to insert and them return an error to the user if it was already inserted, although this is hardly recommended.

Comment: I should have mentioned -- I already have CONSTRAINT article_unq UNIQUE (url) in the create_tables.py, can't figure out why it only works during a session.

Comment: @codi6 can I'm a tad bit unfamiliar with SQLAlchemy, does it keep the SELECT query anywhere? If we take a look at it we might be able to find the error.